# Make IPhone X think it is connecting to a usb drive when plugging into PC - possible using virtual usb drive created with imdisk?

Tags: windows, iphone

I'm wondering if it's feasible to trick my iphone into thinking it's connecting to a flash drive when it connects to my pc.
This article explains how with iOS 13 you can now use flash drives with your phone: https://mbsdirect.com/mbs-blog/article-you-can-now-access-flash-drives-on-an-iphone-or-ipadmdashherersquos-how
The problem is I don't have one of these lightening connector flash drives and want to be able to simulate one via my computer.

I learned a little bit about Imdisk which can create virtual usb drives.  Is it possible to create a virtual usb drive with the right file system (HFS?) that will be presented to the iphone when it's plugged into the usb 3.0 port on my PC?

Comment: To my knowledge neither iOS nor Windows actually supports HFS.  You would only be able to add the support to Windows through the use and installation of the appropriate third-party software.  iOS 10.3+ supports Apple File System (APFS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer is a USB host, not a USB peripheral. It can't act as a USB drive.

On a side note, all USB flash drives generally use FAT32 or exFAT filesystems for interoperability. exFAT is proprietary, but it's supported on Windows, Linux and macOS and doesn't have the 4 GB per file limitation of FAT32.